# Get all the city names from the google maps - group by county

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get a list of all the Hungarian city names from google maps, but I don't know how. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such possibility. Although Google Maps API lets you determine the name of the location by its coordinates (the [Reverse Geocoder API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding)) and lets you find coordinates of places that match the given name query (the [Geocoder API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding)), I'm pretty sure that it won't let you get all objects that match a certain criteria.

So the short answer is: no, it's impossible.